How to trigger event on input date select when value is unchanged?
I am pre-selecting a date on <input type='date' /> and want the user to select a date anyway. If the date selected is the same as the pre-selected value, it does not trigger the change event in jQuery.
Also tried blur and input, but on blur only activates when losing the focus of the element, not on date selection. On input seems to have the same result as on change.
Any ideas how to achieve this?
The pre-selected date is a suggested date which can be chosen or another date could be chosen.
<input id="my-date" type="date" value="2024-07-20" />

// ..

$( '#container' ).on( 'change', '#my-date', function()
{
    console.log( 'selected date: ' + $( this ).val() );
});


Try the input event.

@Barmar the input event is also triggered only when the value is changed

You may need to use a datepicker library instead of the built-in input.

It would be nice to have some code so we can actually debug. But the best way to go about this from what you have given is to select a date that the User is not allowed to select. So your date will be a non-sensible date that the user should not be allowed to select

@Dr. Updated question

"...input, but it only activates when losing the focus of the element, not on date selection." No "input" event happens as the user types into the <input>. Moreover, if the default date is a valid value why is it important to differentiate it from all other values? Also, why is keeping focus on the default date a concern when all other dates are handled when the <input> unfocused?

What is it that you're trying to achieve? Perhaps a more elegant solution is at hand.

I am proposing a solution by making value null while selecting the date:
Working snippet:


var input = document.getElementById('mydate');

input.onclick = function () {
  this.value = null;
};
  
input.onchange = function () {
  console.log(this.value);
};
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="mydate" value="2024-07-24">




Good find! I will try this out!

Solved! Thank you!!

@Z0q I am really glad to help you.

As far as I am aware, there is no way to get a select event in the built-in  date input.
You need to use a datepicker library.
For example jQuery-UI's Datepicker widget, which has a select event.


$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  onSelect(date) {
    console.log(date);
  },
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="2024-07-20">




Instead of using the change event, you should try detecting if the date's new value is the same as its old value.


var old_value = "";

$("#dateinput").val("2024-07-20");

function check(){
  if (old_value != $("#dateinput").val()){
        alert("Value changed"); // Change this to your code
    old_value = $("#dateinput").val()
    }
    setTimeout(check, 10);
}

setTimeout(check, 10);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>

    <input type="date" id="dateinput" value=""><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </body>

</html>




Thank you for your suggestion, good find! Do you think it would be efficient to have this interval running at 10ms?

"try detecting if the date's new value is the same as its old value" You are not doing that. You just reinvented the input event, but still not doing what OP wants.
